# neo4j cypher: multiple queries using WITH keyword

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to run a query which has two parts

```
start cat=node(21) match cat-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(word)-[:FOUND_IN]->doc return doc
```

this query works fine and return the results

```
start cat=node(21) match cat-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->composit-[:COMPOSITE_OF]->(word)-[:FOUND_IN]-single
```

this works OK too and retun empty set

but when I combine them

```
start cat=node(21) match cat-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(word)-[:FOUND_IN]->doc
with cat,doc                                                        
 match cat-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->composit-[:COMPOSITE_OF]->xx-[:FOUND_IN]->single    
 return doc,single
```

no results returned

what Is wrong with It?

Comment: Might not be the best idea there, but have you tried with a single match clause :

    match single <-[:FOUND_IN]- xx <-[:COMPOSITE_OF]- composit -[:HAS_KEYWORD]- 
    cat-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(word)-[:FOUND_IN]->doc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an empty set here, so the second match brings your whole query to an empty set.

Maybe you're looking for `UNION` functionality? This actually came out in 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

change your 2nd `MATCH` to `OPTIONAL MATCH`, so:

```
START cat=node(21)
MATCH (cat)-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(word)-[:FOUND_IN]->(doc)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cat)-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(composit)-[:COMPOSITE_OF]->(xx)-[:FOUND_IN]->(single)
RETURN doc,single
```

Your `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause executes for everything found in your `MATCH` clause, but without reducing the recordset when no results are found.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-optional-match.html